# Omit row if exists another row with the same ID and specific type

Tags: sql, sql-server

DataTable:

[image]

Any time an ID has a record where `Type = A` and a record where `Type = B`, I want to not include the record where `Type = A`.

```
SELECT * FROM DataTable
WHERE Type <> 'A'
```

This query does not work, because I still want to show the record where `Type = A` for ID 500.

Comment: Will Qty always be the same for an ID?

Comment: @jarlh Usually, but not always

Comment: What happen if you have only type A and C for same ID ? In the example A,B,C you keep B and C. But what about A amd C ? Because you say the filter apply  when Type is noth A and B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count()` window analytic function with partitioning by `ID` column and then filter out rows with type equals `A` whenever count is greater than one :

```
with t2 as
(
select t.*, count(*) over (partition by ID order by ID,Qty ) as cnt
  from t
)
select type,ID,Qty
  from t2
 where ( type <> 'A' and  cnt > 1 ) or cnt <= 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0894fa8898a19673a6e721786f9b586a)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Add a `NOT` condition which excludes records where both `type` is 'A' and there exists a record with the same `ID` and of `TYPE` 'B'.

```
SELECT *
FROM DataTable DT1
WHERE not (
  DT1.[Type] = 'A'
  and exists (select 1 from DataTable DT2 where DT2.id = DT1.id and DT2.[Type] = 'B')
)
```

Working example:

```
declare @Test table ([Type] char(1), ID int, Qty int)

insert into @Test ([Type], ID, Qty)
  select 'A', 400, 91 union all
  select 'B', 400, 91 union all
  select 'C', 400, 91 union all
  select 'A', 500, 105;

SELECT *
FROM @Test DT1
WHERE not (
  DT1.[Type] = 'A'
  and exists (select 1 from @Test DT2 where DT2.id = DT1.id and DT2.[Type] = 'B')
)
```

PS - if its SQL Server you should be single quoting your strings, not double quoting them.

Answer (score 0):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where Type <> 'A' 
or not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where Type = 'B' and id = t.id
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=384418a103d5aac3534e38dc29c58c89).
Results:

```
> type |  id | qty
> :--- | --: | --:
> B    | 400 |  91
> C    | 400 |  91
> A    | 500 | 105
```

Comment: This does work but the performance is not ideal for my dataset

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` and `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
select * from DataTable where Type <> 'A'
union
select * from DataTable t1 where Type = 'A' 
and not exists(select 1 from DataTable t2  where t1.id = t2.id and Type = 'B')
```